# What are the two types of memory leaks in Java?

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks

Do these types of memory leaks have fixed names?

Comment: What source talks about two types of memory leaks?

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-leaks/

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it [homework], and please show an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696563/possible-memory-leaks-in-the-java-development-work/6966453#6966453

Answer (score 1):

http://jb2works.com/memoryleak/index.html